# Django User View Affects current_user (solved)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-users

I have url for viewing all info about specific user:

blog/urls.py (I'm using 'urlpatterns +=' to give a piece of urlpatterns list, it's not += in my file)

```
urlpatterns += path('user/<int:pk>/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
```

that uses this UserDetailView View:

blog/views.py

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'blog/user_detail.html'
```

that inherits from DetailView and uses Django's User model.

I have navbar in base html file that displays current user nickname with link to their page attached to it:

base.html(which all other html files inherit from)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">New Post</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'user-detail' user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout-page' %}">Logout</a>
```

Now, when I'm logged in and looking any page except `'user/<int:pk>/'`, nickname with link shows as it should, but when I'm looking some specific user's page, {{ user ]} changes from current user to user who's page I'm looking at: [images](https://imgur.com/a/JEGJzAu).

ListView with Post model that calls User by its nickname does not affect current user:

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns += path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts')
```

blog/views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'   # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html    # blog/post_list.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

[UserPostListView(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XM4a.png).

Is there a way for me to prevent DetailView with User model from changing {{ user }} from current user to one who's page I'm looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to prevent `DetailView` with User model from changing {{ user }} from current user to one who's page I'm looking at?

The reason this happens is because Django injects the object as `object` in the template, but also as the result of a [**`.get_context_object_name(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name) which is by default the name of the model in lowercase, so in this case `user`

But we can obtain the logged in user as `{{ request.user }}` instead so:

```
{{ request.user }}  # 🖘 logged-in user
{{ user }}          # 🖘 object of the DetailView
{{ object }}        # 🖘 object of the DetailView
```

Another option is to specify a different `context_object_name`, like:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'blog/user_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'the_user'
```

Then we thus work with:

```
{{ request.user }}  # 🖘 logged-in user
{{ user }}          # 🖘 logged-in user
{{ the_user }}      # 🖘 object of the DetailView
{{ object }}        # 🖘 object of the DetailView
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you! Tried both options and they all worked fine!